# Remove rows in a csv which has a specific entry in one column and entries in other columns are repeated

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have stumbled upon this problem, which I solved, by hook or by crook. But I need your help in a precise solution. Being a beginner in `awk/sed`, I could not solve it with a one liner (which I am sure there is), or an `awk` script, though with a lot of pipes I could.

Here is the question:

I have a large .csv file with entries similar to this:

file (space delimited)

```
$ cat file
a d e r None
c f g r a
c f g r None
d a d e c
d a d e None
g f r t None
g f t r None
k f r e d
r e t y None
s c d er d
g f r t 4
```

There are no duplicates. But if you see carefully, there are entries in columns 1,2,3,4 that are repeating, and the only change is 5th column, with `'None'`. So I need to remove the rows (records) which are repeating in the 1,2,3,4 fields and that have `None` in 5th column.

Here is the code i wrote, which worked, but no one would recommend:

```
awk '{print $5,$4,$3,$2,$1}' file | sed 's/None/zzz/g' | sort | awk '!array[$2,$3,$4,$5]++' | sed 's/zzz/None/g'
```

and here is the output that I got, and am expecting.

```
4 t r f g
a r g f c
c e d a d
d e r f k
d er d c s
None r e d a
None r t f g
None y t e r
```

Purpose of replacing `None` with `zzz` was after sorting, the rows will appear in the end, and `awk` will remove the second occurrences of the duplicates from remaining columns.
Same is the reason for inverting column sequence and re-inverting it back. Sort.

Please if you could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this solution:

```
awk '{s=$4" "$3" "$2" "$1; if($5=="None"&& s in a)next;else a[s]=$5" "s}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file|sort
```

it outputs:

```
kent$  awk '{s=$4" "$3" "$2" "$1; if($5=="None"&& s in a)next;else a[s]=$5" "s}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file|sort
4 t r f g
a r g f c
c e d a d
d er d c s
d e r f k
None r e d a
None r t f g
None y t e r
```

it seems that it is same as your expectation.

Comment: Thanks @Kent. This works. Took some time to understand though!